# How to isolate dead animal odors in crawlspace?

Tags: smell

Some animal, likely a squirrel or largish animal, obtained entrance to a crawlspace and died there. No one is able to isolate the location of the carcass.  The odor seems to be too ubiquitous in the area to be able to sense strength levels or the origin of the odor.

***Are there any techniques that help to isolate odors of animal carcasses that are buried in insulation or otherwise hidden?***

I've thought that perhaps if we employed a commercial ozone generator and then attempted to "smell it out" again after using this device, that it might reduce the odor enough to detect it based on vicinity, but I'm just taking guesses...

Comment: maybe charcoal might absorb the odor. i don't know if barbeque charcoal would work, but it may be worth a try. ... otherwise, find a dog that loves to roll in rotten things (sort of kidding, but it may work)  .... macabre thought, if you just moved in to the house, maybe you need to call the police

Comment: use air pressure. presuming it's sealed up, or mostly so, use a fan to blow out of a sealed-off opening, like a window or door. Then you can more easily "follow your nose"; non-source area will clear up, whereas if your're between the fan and source, it will still smell. you can switch openings to further eliminate.

Comment: Fresh coffee (ground) spread in a thin layer across something like a baking pan will absorb odor.  Throw the coffee out and replace with new if it loses effectiveness.

Comment: @poorplanning interesting, are there other things that are as cheap as coffee and don't smell as bad? We just can't stand coffee at all and so another option would be nice to have that's also cost effective...

Comment: @ylluminate probably not as cheap, but activated charcoal should work.  You can get it in many pet shops for aquarium filters.

Answer (score 1):

First make sure the area is clean making sure you have no more obvious contributing factors. Then install an exhaust and vent the area 24-7.  As the moisture is displaced and it will eventually be displaced, the odor with dissipate. If you live in a northern climate you will need to monitor the temperature to protect against freezing.

Comment: Yes, freezing is the main issue right now and it also seems to help the odor to persist due to freezing/thawing of the decaying material...